# How could I implement this chunk of code?

Tags: c++, arrays

So my instructor has given me this chunk of code to implement and basically what the overall goal here is to make a checkerboard pattern in a PPM image after writing it to a file. Writing everything to the file is pretty self explanatory to me, the problem is all i am getting are zeros in my array.

Chunk my Instructor gave me.

```
        int col = ((w & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((h & 0x08) == 0);
        raster[i][j].r = static_cast<float>(col);
        raster[i][j].g = static_cast<float>(col & 0x00);
        raster[i][j].b = static_cast<float>(col & 0x11);
```

Here's what I have.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct RGB{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};

int main(){
//Declare Variables
    int h;
    int w;

//User Feedback
    cout << "Please input height then width" << endl;
    cin >> h >> w;

    RGB raster[h][w];

//Assignment loop i = h and j = w
    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < w; j++){
            int col = ((w & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((h & 0x08) == 0);
            raster[i][j].r = static_cast<float>(col);
            raster[i][j].g = static_cast<float>(col & 0x00);
            raster[i][j].b = static_cast<float>(col & 0x11);

            cout << raster[i][j].b << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong i would greatly appreciate it. I have been stuck on the problem and have tried a number of different things thus far.

I have found the issue. My i iterator comes up with a really high value and it's really random. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Have you debugged it? What did you learn?

Comment: Unfortunately I learned that my IDE is really bad and it crashed upon debugging and i had to restart.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? Also, VLAs (`RGB raster[h][w];`) are not supported in _standard_ C++.

Comment: @Tykota Using a full debugger is not the only way to debug. Most of the time I need to debug something small, I use `print` statements (or `cout` in this case). Print out the values of local variables to see where the 0s are coming from. I suck at reasoning about bitwise operations, but I'd have a look at `col`.

Comment: @Tykota Also, get your debugger working. Debuggers are an essential tool in the long-run. You'll need a working one eventually.

Comment: So my VLA issue could be solved pretty easily. Let me try that. I am getting a new IDE as DEV C++ debugger never worked but i never needed it until this point.

Comment: `static_cast<float>(col & 0x00)` is a pretty strange way of writing `0.0f`.

Comment: And since `col` is either `0` or `1`, `static_cast<float>(col & 0x11)` is equivalent to `static_cast<float>(col)`.

Comment: i'm not even sure how to implement VLA's right now honestly.

Comment: I suspect that `h` and `w` in the computation of `col` is just a typo from your instructor. Change them to `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 2):

You are never updating the value of col.

> `int col = ((w & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((h & 0x08) == 0);`

W and h are constant therefore col will be constant.

The result of `==` can only be 0 or 1. Since (1 or 0) xor (1 or 0) can only give (1 or 0) col must be equal (1 or 0).

When you are setting

`raster[i][j].b = static_cast<float>(col & 0x11);`

The `&` does nothing because your col value can only be 1 or 0.

Are you sure the col variable is being set correctly?

Comment: It's supposed to be only 0 or 1. The end result is a checkboard pattern in a PPM file

Comment: I have to convert it to 0 - 225 used in PPM

Comment: Then why AND it? The AND does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your code by adding `print` statements to it. For example:

```
    for(int j = 0; j < w; j++){
        int col = ((w & 0x08) == 0) ^ ((h & 0x08) == 0);
        std::cout << "First part: " << ((w & 0x08) == 0) << '\n';
        std::cout << "Second part: " << ((h & 0x08) == 0) << '\n';
        std::cout << "col = " << col << '\n';
        ...
    }
```

Your specific case has an error in `col` calculation - it should use e.g. `j` instead of `w`.

BTW other things in your code given by instructor look suspicious. You might want to ask him for explanations on what the code does and why. Or (better) writing the code yourself - it's small enough to rewrite completely.

Comment: Thank you. Also he is the type of instructor to throw weird stuff at us. He hands out Zeros like candy.

Comment: Also this did it! My col value now varies! Thank you so much. I really just overlooked that part.

Comment: My col value no longer varies as my i in the program shows up as a large negative number right now and i'm not really sure why. I have been debugging.